# Defining Tags in Reap

Tags: functions, result-accumulation, sow-reap

I am trying to use `Sow`/`Reap` to replace `Append` in my code. The problem is that I need to define the tags within my code, but doing so doesn't reap the desired results. A simplified version of my code is

```
Clear[tag];
Reap[tag = {a,b}; Sow[1, a];Sow[2,b];, tag]
```

However, if I define my tag outside of Reap, then it works

```
Clear[tag];
tag = {a,b};
Reap[Sow[1, a];Sow[2,b];, tag]
```

Any ideas as to how I can define tags within my code?

Comment: In short, the reason is the `HoldFirst` attribute of `Reap`.  This attribute is necessary for `Reap` to be influence the evaluation of its first argument.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think what is basically asked here is whether or not `Reap` can work with filtering tags which are only known when the code inside `Reap` is running. In such formulation, it makes perfect sense, but alas the answer is no. But one can always filter after the fact, and with a similar run-time performance (but possibly at the expense of memory use).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Reap` does not work that way: when you provide a list of tags for `Reap` only these tags are "watched for" and collected.  This allows for much better memory management than collecting for *all* tags and discarding at the end.

In essence it works something like this for declared tags `1`, `2`, `3`:

```
{one, two, three} = {{},{},{}};

sow[x_, 1] := (one   = {one, x};   x)
sow[x_, 2] := (two   = {two, x};   x)
sow[x_, 3] := (three = {three, x}; x)
sow[x_, _] := x

SeedRandom[1]
Do[sow[i, RandomInteger[10^6]], {i, 10^7}]

Flatten /@ {one, two, three}

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {{30003, 1238414, 1529333, 3074569, 3401105, 4162839, 4715096, 5855206, 5971795, 6984287},
>  {238730, 652982, 946353, 1821955, 2018277, 2065726, 4483637,
>   4591412, 4733380, 4920935, 5283043, 5816356, 8272260, 8409277},
>  {2793919, 2803799, 3784289, 5018439, 6380588, 8799862, 9301537}}
>
> 15034792
> ```

You can see that advance knowledge of the tags is needed to set this up.  Compare to the memory requirements of this:

```
SeedRandom[1]

Cases[
 {#[[All, 1]], #[[1, 2]]} & /@
   Table[{i, RandomInteger[10^6]}, {i, 10^7}] ~GatherBy~ Last,
 {_, 1 | 2 | 3},
 {1}
]

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {{{30003, 1238414, 1529333, 3074569, 3401105, 4162839, 4715096, 
>    5855206, 5971795, 6984287}, 1},
>  {{238730, 652982, 946353, 1821955, 2018277, 2065726, 4483637, 
>    4591412, 4733380, 4920935, 5283043, 5816356, 8272260, 8409277}, 2},
>  {{2793919, 2803799, 3784289, 5018439, 6380588, 8799862, 9301537}, 3}}
>
> 605960144
> ```

---

If you wish to replace `Append` with something more efficient, consider using [linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5797991/618728) as I did in the `sow` example above, or the [`` Internal`Bag `` class of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762/618728).