# Partitioning lists by length of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose we have the following list

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 0}, {6, 7, 8}, {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1}, 
        {-2, -3, -4}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

As we can see, some of the sublists have 3 elements, while others have 5 elements. I want the following: create two new lists `lts3` and `lst5` one with the 3-elements sublists and the other with all the 5-elements sublists.

```
lst3 = {{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 8}, {-2, -3, -4}};
lst5 = {{4, 3, 2, 1, 0}, {-5, -4, -3, -2,- 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are no newbie around here (>100 Q´s) -- do you really have no clue as how to go about that?

Comment: @YvesKlett I see your point. Surely I can find a way to solve this issue but I'm always looking for new elegant and quick solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GatherBy[exp, Length`] would work. Here exp is the expression.

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions I would turn to [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) for this:

```
GroupBy[data, Length] /@ {3, 5}
```

Note: [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html) can be [somewhat faster](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121) than `Map`.

If memory consumption is a concern consider using the older [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) as you can preselect the targets, e.g. `Reap[Sow[#, Length@#] & ~Scan~ data, {3, 5}][[2, All, 1]]` See [Defining Tags in Reap](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/defining-tags-in-reap/6429#6429).

Comment: `GroupBy`   is a nice function. [This](http://i.imgur.com/dAEqLPr.jpg) made me think of you :)

Comment: @ubpdqn I guess that makes me forgotten bastard? ;-)  -- thanks for the laugh. :^)

Comment: Nice use of tags in Sow, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to use Select:

```
lst3 = Select[data, Length[#] == 3 &]
```

and

```
lst5 = Select[data, Length[#] == 5 &]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{lst3, lst5} = GatherBy[data, Length];
```

[image]